# Dependency Registrar for other assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a simple question about dependecy registration.

I'm developing a brand new web application that use Engine Context paradigm with Autofac container. For any library on the solution I have one class implementing `IDependencyRegistrar` that implement a common `Register` method, due to add one the container some specific implementation of some interfaces and components.

In this way, a base Core library (running at application startup) provide a `RegisterDependencies` method that lookup on every Executing Assembly to discover all the DDL's used by the application and registering them on Autofac Container.

The code that provide this behavior is:

```
 builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var drTypes = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IDependencyRegistrar>();
        var drInstances = new List<IDependencyRegistrar>();
        foreach (var drType in drTypes)
            drInstances.Add((IDependencyRegistrar) Activator.CreateInstance(drType));
        //sort
        drInstances = drInstances.AsQueryable().OrderBy(t => t.Order).ToList();
        foreach (var dependencyRegistrar in drInstances)
            dependencyRegistrar.Register(builder, typeFinder, config);
        builder.Update(container);
```

Where the `FindClassOfType<IDependencyRegistrar>` works thanks to a Method implementation like that:

```
        public virtual IList<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var addedAssemblyNames = new List<string>();
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        if (LoadAppDomainAssemblies)
            AddAssembliesInAppDomain(addedAssemblyNames, assemblies);
        AddConfiguredAssemblies(addedAssemblyNames, assemblies);

        return assemblies;
    }
```

And, `AddAssemblyInAppDomain` is:

```
private void AddAssembliesInAppDomain(List<string> addedAssemblyNames, List<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            if (Matches(assembly.FullName))
            {
                if (!addedAssemblyNames.Contains(assembly.FullName))
                {
                    assemblies.Add(assembly);
                    addedAssemblyNames.Add(assembly.FullName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The problem is:** when I end up on adding in mysolution the MVC project (the front-end), I've referenced on it only direct accessing library (service layer and some infrastructure components) but no DataLayer components and some other DLL. Due to the fact that MVC not referencing directly some libraries of deep layers, my Engine Context doesn't see the others sub-components and not registering them on the Autofac container, causing a

> 'no registered services'

exception when execution make explicit request on them.

The whole system just works if I add reference to any library from the MVC project but, for layered architectured application, this is not a best practice: my MVC need to know nothing about DataLayer or others low-layered services.

However, in this way, no ExecutingAssembly are discovered, so, not dependency are registered anymore.

Wich is the best approch to resolve this situation without referencing all assemblies directly from main MVC project?

Comment: I've found that the problem may be caused by another issue. My DAL library was not referenced by Model library (a mix of model and service classes) but, this has configured as reverse dependency. My Model library has an DAL interface and the DAL Project reference the Model, implementing these interfaces. So, dependency are: MVC --> Model <-- DAL. I think that this is the problem: no ones directly referencing the DAL so, if I compile MVC, DAL library was not copied into BIN Dir. May be this the problem? If it is, what I can do to workaround it without change my dependency architecture?

Comment: I had this exact same problem with autofac and a console app. With web projects it seems to be easier but non-web projects I couldn't find a nice way of getting all transitive dependencies to be detected and loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is described in Autofac documentation as *Assembly Scanning*, take a look [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html#iis-hosted-web-applications). Basically, to get all assemblies in IIS-hosted application you need this piece of code:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
```

EDIT:

Ok, so I understand the situation is like this:

Project *Web* is a MVC web app.

Project *Model* is a class library where you have your contracts (interfaces) defined, e.g. for DAL, but also for *Web*.

Project *DAL* contains some implementations of contracts from *Model*.

There might be some additional class libraries, but they all uses *Model* for contracts.

So to sum up - all projects have reference to *Model*, but they have no references to each other.

I think for every library (except *Model*) you should create a module. To do so, create a class implementing `Module` type from `Autofac` library and override `Load` method - put all your module registration in there. Then, in *Web* app start you should load all assemblies and register their modules. But, as you mentioned, assemblies other than *Web* are not present in *bin* directory; you should copy them there "manually", for example in Post-Build action (Project Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build action). The following command should do the work:

```
xcopy /Y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)..\{Your Web App}\bin"
```

Also, in your solution properties you should set, that *Web* project "depends" on all other projects. It would assure all other libraries would be build before *Web*. It does not add any reference between these assemblies.

Then, during application startup, you should search for you assemblies in *bin* folder and register each assembly module, like this:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

var libFolder = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin"));
var libFiles = libFolder.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var lib in libFiles)
{
     var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(lib.FullName);
     containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(asm);
}

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

You might want to add some filter to `libFolder.GetFiles()` to retreive only your assemblies, not all from *bin*.

If your other assemblies contains Mvc Controllers, you should take a look how to manage the situation [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#using-plugin-assemblies) (see `Initializer` class). Basically, in pre-start of application you would need to add assemblies to `BuildManager`. Otherwise, the code above should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much tdragon. I try this soon and I promise to give you a feedback on your answer.

Comment: Sorry tdragon, your solution doesn't work: if I remove direct reference to my sub-layered libraries (for example, DAL) the container not register that. The problem is that those libraries wasn't copied to bin directory if the MVC project not referencing it, so, in this manner, GetReferencedAssembly can't scan it and not register. The problem start, I think, inside of the project configuration. How I can say to Visual Studio to copy any library of the solution, independent of the fact that such library was referenced by the main project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielGrandis ok, now I get what you did mean. Yes - you have to copy all dlls to bin by yourself. I think the best way to do so is using Post-Build actions in each .csproj to copy these files - you can use Windows' xcopy command

Comment: @DanielGrandis I edited my answer to reflect your situation

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a ***non-web*** project then my answer might help?

To your Ioc class add a method i.e:

```
    public static void SetIocForTesting(bool forUnitTesting)
    {
        _testContext = forUnitTesting;
    }
```

Sample container set-up code, delegate out the responsibility of getting the assemblies to load into the builder. i.e GetModules():

```
    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container != null)
            {
                return _container;
            }

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            foreach (var lib in GetModules())
            {
                builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(lib);
            }

            _container = builder.Build();
            return _container;
        }
    }
```

When scanning for Assemblies, switch on the testContext variable:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetModules()
    {
        if (_testContext)
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        }

        var currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (currentPath == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to build the container because currentPath variable is null.");
        }
        // XXXX = assign a wild card
        var libFolder = new DirectoryInfo(currentPath);
        var libFiles = libFolder.GetFiles("XXXX.*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        return libFiles.Select(lib => Assembly.LoadFrom(lib.FullName)).ToList();
    }
```

When unit testing your IoC provider and a registration:

```
    protected virtual void GivenThat()
    {
        IocProvider.SetIocForTesting(true);
    }
```

.. you have a method that switches the IoC to ensure it works correctly with all assemblies referenced and loaded by your test project. The above method lives inside an abstract base class I use for BDD style unit testing.

Your test project usually ends up referencing a lot of assemblies which means resolving services have a higher success rate.

Finally, for non UnitTesting code add a static constructor:

```
static IocProvider()
{
    _testContext = false;
}
```

This will ensure a default work flow for production code.

Feel free to play with the above format to suit your needs; I hope it helps someone in the way the above question and answer helped me.